# Apache Http 4.5 StringBody Constructor Not Exporting Content Type in Request

Tags: docusignapi, apache-httpclient-4.x

Using Apache Http 4.5 MultipartEntityBuilder and can't seem to figure out why the StringBody(String, ContentType) constructor doesn't actually output the Content-Type in the request form body.

```
public HttpRequestBase build() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes");

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.setBoundary("AAA");

    //add form body
    builder.addPart(generateJsonFormBodyPart());

    //add file body
    builder.addPart(generateFileFormBodyPart()); //<--intentionally omitted

    HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();

    httpPost.setEntity(multipart);

    return httpPost;

}

private FormBodyPart generateJsonFormBodyPart() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        StringBody json = new StringBody(packageJson(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON); //<--THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK    
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        buffer.append("form-data");

        String contentDisposition = buffer.toString();

        FormBodyPartBuilder partBuilder = FormBodyPartBuilder.create("application/json", json);
        partBuilder.setField(MIME.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition);

        FormBodyPart fbp = partBuilder.build();

        return fbp;
    }
```

The file portion outputs ok but I get a "Bad Request" return from the peer which I assume is because it has very specific request parameters.

---

**Required Request Output**

Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA

--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

**json removed**

--AAA
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test1.pdf";documentid=1

**document removed**

---

**Actual Apache Http 4.5 Output**

X-Docusign-Act-As-User: xyz@company.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_65)
Connect-Time: 0
Host: requestb.in
Connection: close
Content-Length: 3178
Authorization: bearer  xxxxrandomoauthtokenxxxxx
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA; charset=ISO-8859-1
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Request-Id: 89cd1cf5-3615-41e8-84ba-cd076a03af67
Total-Route-Time: 0

--AAA
Content-Disposition: **form-data**  //<--the problem. should be application/json no?

{"status":"created","emailBlurb":"Welcome to Confluence","emailSubject":"Welcome to Confluence","documents":{"name":"Welcome to Confluence.html","documentId":"1","order":"1"},"recipients":{}}

--AAA
Content-Disposition: file; filename="Welcome.html";documentid=1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

**h t m l string removed**

**Q: So why does the ContentType in the StringBody constructor get ignored?  Is there a workaround or am I doing it wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

I'm convinced this is a bug in Apache Http Mime for the FormBodyPart.build() when processing a StringBody.  Evidence from release notes of 4.5.2 indicating bug fixes for other "body" types not outputting "Content-Type" supports this.  I will be logging a defect.

**The Workaround:**

```
private FormBodyPart generateJsonFormBodyPart() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBody json = new StringBody(getMyJsonStuff(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON); //<--THE GOGGLES, THEY DO NOTHING!!

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append("form-data");
    buffer.append("\r\n");
    buffer.append("Content-Type: application/json"); //<--tack this on to the 

    String kludgeForDispositionAndContentType = buffer.toString();

    FormBodyPartBuilder partBuilder = FormBodyPartBuilder.create("stuff", json);
    partBuilder.setField(MIME.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, kludgeForDispositionAndContentType);

    FormBodyPart fbp = partBuilder.build();

    return fbp;
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks @Kling! I ran into this problem earlier but couldn't figure out what was missing. I see the problem now. Can you mark your post as the correct answer please?

Comment: Thanks， really help solve my  problem. I use apache 4.5.13